# DISTINCT based on ID between Two table and SUM of the other exiting column in SQL

Tags: sql

```
SELECT 
    SUM(amount), (DISTINCT table1.id) 
FROM 
    table1
INNER JOIN 
    table2 ON table1.id = table2.id IS NULL;

Table1   id    amount        Table2   id    product
         1        40                   5        10 
         2    364.25                   2        20
         3      704.5                  8        30
         4      404.5                  3        40
         5      580.5                  2        20
```

The id is not unique or primary ------------------first i need to ignore all double entry ID from table2 then match id from table2 to table1 after that those ids will be match i need total of amount figure amount is a column name i will not calculate single the data will be more than 20000. please help me if you can

First compare match table2 id with table1 id if found any id match then those id amount need to be SUM i mean total. here match id is 2 and 3 according to table2 and then we will add this 2 and 3 id amount so result will be 364.25+704.5=1068.75 i am looking the result how can i do it using mysql.

I am trying to `DISTINCT` based on `ID` between two tables and `SUM` of the other existing column we have in table1. Can somebody help me how to do it?

Comment: Please post sample data and your expected output.  It is not at all clear what you are trying to do here.

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: could you update you question adding a proper data sample and the expected  esult?

Comment: Please Check the question The data is updated............and help me

Comment: If you want distinct ID then you should sum on that ID.  Do you really want to sum all matching ID's and attach that same sum to each ID that matches?  Your example would output 2, 1068.75   3, 1068.75.   This is why folks ask for sample output as well...

Comment: Please post sample output

Comment: Hi, @JoeC i am looking which ID's will be match there total of amount figure here if we match ID  table2 to table1 then we got 2 ID like 2and 3 after that we need to  SUM of amount figure this 2 and 3 ID's table1 if we see  Amount like 364.25 and 704.5  total will be 1068.75 i am looking this total . I am looking the result 1068.75.

Comment: I dont understand where distinct comes in then if you only want one row - grand total.  I will post the query based on this and ignore distinct for now.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: the question is updated please see and help me. For mysql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your latest comment try this

```
SELECT 
    SUM(amount)
FROM 
    table1
INNER JOIN 
    (Select Distinct ID From table2) T2 ON table1.id = T2.id
```

Comment: it will be work but if i use this one there is some problem like if the id is not primary or unique the id  will be double id in table2 for this reason i need to use  DISTINCT that double id will be ignore.

Comment: MySQL said: Documentation
#1054 - Unknown column 'amount' in 'field list'

Answer (score 0):

From what I understood, you need common IDs from both table and corresponding sum of amount.

```
SELECT
    SUM(amount)
FROM 
    table1
WHERE
    id IN (SELECT id
    FROM table2);
```

Comment: t1 means i am not familler with t1 is it possible to clear for me what you mean about t1

Comment: `t1` is an alias for `table1`. Similarly `t2` is alias for table `table2`. It eases query writing or else repeatedly writing full table name would become troublesome.

Comment: Here we need to double id ignore form Table2 then need to rest of the thing.

Answer (score 0):

Lets leave a matter of performance beyond the topic:)
So according to this:

> First compare match table2 id with table1 id if found any id match
>   then those id amount need to be SUM i mean total

it is possible to use correlated subquery:

```
select sum(t1.amount)
from table1 t1 
where exists (select 1 from table2 t2 where t2.id = t1.id)
```